# Error em uma function com callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

js e entrando em callback estou com um problema
error:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\SpiriT\Documents\estudo\callback\index.js:4:16)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
PS C:\Users\SpiriT\Documents\estudo\callback>
```

meu codigo:

```
function getUser(callback){
    setTimeout( () => {
        return callback(null, {
            id: 1,
            nome: 'gabriel',
            dataNascimento: new Date()
        })
    },1000)
}

function getPhone(idUsuario,callback){ //callback sempre no ultimo param
    setTimeout( () => {
        return callback(null, {
            telefone:'99492566',
            dd:73
        })
    },1000)
}

function getAddress(idUsuario,callback){
    setTimeout( () => {
        return callback(null,{
            rua: 'Fatima',
            numero: '197'
        })
    },1000)
}

getUser(function resolveUser(error,usuario){
    if(error){
        console.error('fail in user', error);
        return;
    }
    getPhone(usuario.id, function resolvePhone(error1,phone){
        if(error1){
            console.error('fail in phone', error1);
            return;
        } 
    })
    getAddress(usuario.id, function resolveAddrsss(error2,address){
        if(error2){
            console.error('fail in address', error2);
            return;
        } 
    })
})

const usuario = getUser();
const phone = getPhone();
const address = getAddress();
```

Comment: Você deve passar o parâmetro dentro do timeout após o tempo em milisegundos. Exemplo: `}, 1000, callback)`

Comment: continuou com o mesmo error @LeonardoGetulio

Comment: Acontece que em `getUser()`, `getPhone()` e `getAddress()` você não está passando o *callback*, por isso o erro. Para corrigir, adicione `if (!(callback instanceof Function)) return` antes de todos os *return callback(..)*

Comment: Eu achei estranho eu tava seguindo um curso e fiz qse igual apenas mudando nome das functions e etc e tinha dado error fui conferir no video e tinha feito igualzinho .

Comment: @ValdeirPsr você poderia responder como ficaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que, quando o código `const usuario = getUser();` é executado, a função `getUser` deveria receber um *callback*. Há algumas formas de corrigir esse erro.

Na primeira, podemos verificar se a variável `callback` é, ou não, uma função. Para isso, podemos utilizar o operador [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Com esse operador, podemos verificar se determinada variável é do mesmo tipo que determinada classe ou função.

```js
function getUser(callback){
    /**
     * Verifica o callback é uma função
     * Caso não seja, retorna vazio e
     * não executa a função `setTimeout`
     */
     if (!(callback instanceof Function)) return

    setTimeout( () => {
    return callback(null, {
            id: 1,
            nome: 'gabriel',
            dataNascimento: new Date()
        })
    },1000)
}

function getPhone(idUsuario,callback){ //callback sempre no ultimo param
    /**
     * Verifica o callback é uma função
     * Caso não seja, retorna vazio e
     * não executa a função `setTimeout`
     */     
     if (!(callback instanceof Function)) return
    
    setTimeout( () => {
        return callback(null, {
            telefone:'99492566',
            dd:73
        })
    },1000)
}

function getAddress(idUsuario,callback){
    /**
     * Verifica o callback é uma função
     * Caso não seja, retorna vazio e
     * não executa a função `setTimeout`
     */     
    if (!(callback instanceof Function)) return
    
    setTimeout( () => {
        return callback(null,{
            rua: 'Fatima',
            numero: '197'
        })
    },1000)
}

const usuario = getUser();
const phone = getPhone();
const address = getAddress();

getUser(function resolveUser(error,usuario){
    if(error){
        console.error('fail in user', error);
        return;
    }
    getPhone(usuario.id, function resolvePhone(error1,phone){
        if(error1){
            console.error('fail in phone', error1);
            return;
        } 
    })
    getAddress(usuario.id, function resolveAddrsss(error2,address){
        if(error2){
            console.error('fail in address', error2);
            return;
        } 
    })
})
```

Além da forma supra, podemos passar uma *arrow function* vazia. Dessa forma estaremos passando um *callback*, evitando os erros.

```js
function getUser(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'gabriel',
      dataNascimento: new Date()
    })
  }, 1000)
}

function getPhone(idUsuario, callback) { //callback sempre no ultimo param
  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      telefone: '99492566',
      dd: 73
    })
  }, 1000)
}

function getAddress(idUsuario, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      rua: 'Fatima',
      numero: '197'
    })
  }, 1000)
}

getUser(function resolveUser(error, usuario) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('fail in user', error);
    return;
  }
  getPhone(usuario.id, function resolvePhone(error1, phone) {
    if (error1) {
      console.error('fail in phone', error1);
      return;
    }
  })
  getAddress(usuario.id, function resolveAddrsss(error2, address) {
    if (error2) {
      console.error('fail in address', error2);
      return;
    }
  })
})

const usuario = getUser( _ => {} ); //Informa uma arrow function
const phone = getPhone( null, _ => {} ); //Informa uma arrow function
const address = getAddress( null, _ => {} ); //Informa uma arrow function
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução não é alterar as funções para finalizar se `callback` não estiver definido. Nesse contexto isso é tratar o sintomas sem tratar a causa. Em alguns lugares do país chamam isso de gambiarra.

O erro acontece justamente nessas chamadas, que você não define a função `callback`:

```js
const usuario = getUser();
const phone = getPhone();
const address = getAddress();
```

Porém essas linhas de código estão avulsas e não possuem propósito algum. Então por que editar sua solução para resolver um problema criado por um código que nem deveria existir? Basta excluir essas linhas.

```js
function getUser(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'gabriel',
      dataNascimento: new Date()
    })
  }, 1000)
}

function getPhone(idUsuario, callback) {
  if (!(callback instanceof Function)) return

  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      telefone: '99492566',
      dd: 73
    })
  }, 1000)
}

function getAddress(idUsuario, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return callback(null, {
      rua: 'Fatima',
      numero: '197'
    })
  }, 1000)
}

getUser(function(error, usuario) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('fail in user', error);
    return;
  }

  console.log("Usuario", usuario);

  getPhone(usuario.id, function(error1, phone) {
    if (error1) {
      console.error('fail in phone', error1);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Telefone", phone);
  })

  getAddress(usuario.id, function(error2, address) {
    if (error2) {
      console.error('fail in address', error2);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Endereço", address);
  })
})
```

Adicionei alguns `console.log` para exibir os dados obtidos em caso de sucesso.